# Issue in running a ballerina service

Tags: ballerina

I have ran a ballerina service by the terminal and i killed the terminal. But when i try to re-run the ballerina service, in background the service was already running and the port was in use. How can I terminate a ballerina service and re-run it using the terminal?
This is the message I got.
Please help me with this?
Thank you!

[image: this is the message i got]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following

```sh
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:37070)
```